# What happens when a package is duplicate in sources?

Tags: apt

I'm just about to install Owncloud. I found an owncloud package in the standard ubuntu sources. 
But the instructions say, I need to add a new softwaresource.
So what happens, after I added the source and I do 
`sudo apt-get install owncloud`?

Which package will be installed? And how does apt-get know which package it should install?

[edit]
Thanks to Braiams post, here is the versiontable of owncloud. Just to show you how it looks like:

```
owncloud:  
    Installiert:           6.0.0a-0  
    Installationskandidat: 6.0.0a-0  
    Versionstabelle:  
   *** 6.0.0a-0 0  
          500 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:community/xUbuntu_13.10/  Packages  
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status  
       5.0.12+dfsg-1ubuntu1~saucy1 0
          500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe amd64 Packages  
       5.0.10+dfsg-1ubuntu1 0  
          500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what happens, after I added the source and I do sudo apt-get install owncloud?
>
> Which package will be installed?

The package with greater version number will be installed and if they have the same version number, then it will select the one has their entry first in the `sources.list`. You can check the Candidate version using apt-cache:

```
apt-cache policy owncloud
owncloud:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.13+dfsg-2
  Version table:
     5.0.13+dfsg-2 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
```

(I'm using Debian, but it get you an idea).

> And how does apt-get know which package it should install?

Looking at the package lists cache that gets downloaded and updated each time you do `update`.